# Как в JS совершить математическую операцию с полученной из input переменной?

Tags: javascript

есть код на JS, который получает данные из input и передает в переменную kevt, а затем значение этой переменной передается в стиль width другого объекта:

```
document.querySelector('#input-width').addEventListener('input', kevt => { 
    var width = kevt;
    document.querySelector('#square').style.width = width.target.value + 'px'; 
})
```

как мне полученную переменную kevt разделить на 10 и передать дальше в стиль width?

P.S.: kevt/10 или kevt*0.1 не работает - данные не передаются в width

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Всё вполне себе работает. Только надо работать не с `kevt` а `width.target.value`. Либо из `kevt.target.value` доставать значение

```js
document.querySelector('#input-width').addEventListener('input', kevt => { 
    var width = kevt;
    document.querySelector('#square').style.width = width.target.value / 10 + 'px'; 
})
```

```css
div {
  border: 1px solid black;
}
```

```html
<input id="input-width" />

<div id="square">1</div>
```

Comment: Спасибо, всё работает! Я знал, что решение должно быть простое, но не мог понять какое :)